# How do I map the Windows key to meta (for Emacs) in Putty?

Tags: windows, emacs, putty, metadata

How do I map the Windows key to meta (for Emacs) in Putty?

Answer (score 0):

Putty does not have keyboard mapping (though there is a [feature request](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/key-mapping.html))

Perhaps [this EMACS wiki article](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PuTTY#toc8) is helpful?